# Numpy: vectorizing two-branch test (ternary-operator like)

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am vectorizing a test in Numpy for the following idea: perform *elementwise* some test and pick *expr1* or *expr2* according to the test. This is like the *ternary-operator* in C: `test?expr1:expr2`

I see two major ways for performing that; I would like to know if there is a good reason to choose one rather than the other one; maybe also other tricks are available and I would be very happy to know about them. Main goal is speed; for that reason I don't want to use `np.vectorize` with an `if-else` statement.

For my example, I will re-build the `min` function; please, don't tell me about some Numpy function for computing that; this is a mere example!

**Idea 1**: Use the arithmetic value of the booleans in a multiplication:

```
# a and b have similar shape
test = a < b
ntest = np.logical_not(test)
out = test*a + ntest*b
```

**Idea 2**: More or less following the APL/J style of coding (by using the conditional expression as an index for an array made with one dimension more than initial arrays).

```
# a and b have similar shape
np.choose(a<b, np.array([b,a]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a better way to use `choose`

```
np.choose(a<b, [b,a])
```

In my small timings it is faster.  Also the `choose` doc says `If`choices`is itself an array (not recommended), ....`

```
(a<b).choose([b,a])
```

saves one level of function redirection.

Another option:

```
out = b.copy(); out[test] = a[test]
```

In quick tests this actually faster.  `masked.filled` uses `np.copyto` for this sort of 'where' copy, though it doesn't seem to be any faster.

A variation on the `choose` is `where`:

```
np.where(test,a,b)
```

Or use `where` (or `np.nonzero`) to convert boolean index to a numeric one:

```
I = np.where(test); out = b.copy(); out[I] = a[I]
```

For some reason this times faster than the one-piece where.

I've used the multiplication approach in the past; if I recall correctly even with APL (though that's decades ago). An old trick to avoid divide by 0 was to add `n==0`, `a/(b+(b==0))`. But it's not as generally applicable.  `a*0`, `a*1` have to make sense.

`choose` looks nice, but with the `mode` parameter may be more powerful (and hence complicated) that needed.

I'm not sure there is a 'best' way.  timing tests can evaluate certain situations, but I don't know where they can be generalized across all cases.